# how to define an object method that takes an argument of the object's type

Tags: python-3.x

Here is a case where it would be sensible to give the type hint of an argument of an object's method as the object itself.

```
class ImagePath:
def __init__(self, path:Path, size:int):
    self.path = path
    self.size = size

def __eq__(self, other:ImagePath):
    return self.path == other.path and self.size == other.size
```

However, this gives an error:

```
    NameError: name 'ImagePath' is not defined
```

Is there a way to construct the method with the correct type hint?

PS. I am aware that the method will respond the same way without the equality method, but this was a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Put ImagePath in quotes, like this:

```
class ImagePath:
    def __init__(self, path:Path, size:int):
        self.path = path
        self.size = size

    def __eq__(self, other:'ImagePath'):
        return self.path == other.path and self.size == other.size
```

See PEP 484 section [Forward Reference](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references)

Comment: See my comments above. I believe they apply equally to using Python3.7+ or importing annotations in Python3.6. However, I am not in a position to test this right now.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Python 3.7, with [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/), you can use `from __future__ import annotations` to store annotations as strings. From PEP 563:

> This PEP proposes changing function annotations and variable
> annotations so that they are no longer evaluated at function
> definition time. Instead, they are preserved in __annotations__ in
> string form.
>
> This change is being introduced gradually, starting with a __future__
> import in Python 3.7.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

class ImagePath:
    def __init__(self, path:tuple, size:int):
        self.path = path
        self.size = size

    def __eq__(self, other:ImagePath):
        return self.path == other.path and self.size == other.size
    
ImagePath((10,22),20) == ImagePath((10,22),20)
# True
ImagePath((10,22),20) == ImagePath((10,), 20)
# False
```

Comment: This seems to work. It has the disadvantage of postponing an error notification until the method is called while running. There may be other values to type hinting but the value that I have come to like most is getting the errors at compile time.  In an IDE such as PyCharm, you usually see those errors when you first type the erroneous line.

Reading PEPs 563 and 484 it appears that the Python community has settled on this approach. I am sure they weighted the loss of compile-time errors against other practical issues.